# How to make a modal appear without pushing the rest of the page down?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, z-index

I want the modal to be at the center of the page and appear on top of the .main when I activate the .hidden class via javascript.
But when I enable the .hidden class, the .main gets pushed down, even though I have given the .modal a higher z-index.

What am I doing wrong?

https://codepen.io/boatus/pen/abWxzwL

```
           .modal {
          background-color: rgb(162, 154, 170);
          width: 70vw;
          height: 70vh;
           margin: auto;
         position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
         } 

          .main {
            display: flex;
           justify-content: center;
            margin: 40px;
          gap: 100px;
         z-index: 1;
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of position `relative`, you have to use position `absolute`,

simple add this css to your `.modal` class:

```
 position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
```

Comment: Thanks! So the relative position moves an element within its own block, whereas an absolute position moves an element within the entire body of the page?
I also didn't really understand the "transform:translate(-50%,-50%);" part.

Comment: @boatus yes, relative position moves an element within its own block. 

whereas an absolute position moves an element within the entire body of the page- until it founds a parent, with position relative. If any parent has position relative then absolute will take position of relative parent, else body.

transform:translate(-50,-50) its just to make div in centre, translate takes two values x and y. Without it your div will not be in centre. You may play with it in order to understand.